# Mysql daemon failed to start: unknown variable password=xxx

Tags: mysql, startup

Mysqld don't restart anymore...In the log, the apparently obvious reason:

```
mysqld started
[Warning] Ignoring user change to 'root' because the user was set to 'mysql' earlier on the command line
[ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: unknown variable 'password=mypassword'
mysqld ended
```

/etc/my.cnf there is nothing relevant and there is no such variable, which by the way has the correct mysql root password value in the message (!!!?):

```
[mysqld]
user=mysql
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
[mysqld_safe] 
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

Mysql 5.0.95 on Centos 5.9. It worked ok before restarting!!

Tried also

```
 /usr/bin/mysqld_safe --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --no-defaults
Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
STOPPING server from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
mysqld ended
```

Comment: Something tells me `--no-defaults` needs to be the first option, though that may or may not be right.  At any rate, `mysqld --help --verbose | less` should include a list of the various places it could be loading that file from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed the last suggestion [here](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=31312)

```
cd /usr
./mysqld_safe --defaults-file=/etc/my.cnf --user=mysql --ledir=/usr/libexec &
```

Now it started, but don't understand it...not very nice!!!

Answer (score -1):

I'v got same problem.
Just deleted password line from /etc/my.conf and mysqld started
Have no idea what was that...